# how to add value to model property in MVC5 view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In my model there are following properties:
1. a decimal property Total- value is 10
2. a list of chocolates and their prices - let's say value is A with price 20 and B with price 30

This model is passed to View. View shows a checkbox against each chocoloate.

When user checks any checkbox the Total property needs to be updated by adding the corresponding chocolate price - This is what's not working.

I have written a function which is called for all the checkboxes when checked/unchecked. Inside this function whatever I write it gives me the following error:

> Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I am trying to add like the following, lets say price of the checked chocolate is 20:
`@Model.Total = @Model.Total + 20;`
even tried using a temp variable and then assigning - doesn't work.

I am using MVC5, jquery, javascript, bootstrap

Please help me solve this.

Following is the code for `Index.cshtml` ( the javascript function to add to the base price is the one that gives an error):

```
@model WebApplication8.Models.Cart

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    <h4>Cart</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
         <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BasePrice)
         </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BasePrice)
        </dd>
    </dl>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="name" onchange="OnPriceChange(@item.Price)"    /> @item.Name
    }
</div>
<script>
    function OnPriceChange(val) {
        @Model.BasePrice = @Model.BasePrice + val;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your function that gives the error and your view code for the checkboxes/chocolates.

Comment: have added the code..please check

Comment: Have you looked at what gets sent to the client from your script (View Source)? I suspect that for a model whose BasePrice is $11.99, you're sending a script to the client that reads `function OnPriceChange(val) {  $11.99 = $11.99 + val; }` This is, of course, nonsense, and that's what the `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error is telling you. You're using server-side code to *try* to write a client-side script.

Comment: As Kevin has said, you are confusing Razor (server-side) template paceholders for javascript (client-side) variables. Your `@Model.BasePrice` is not a javascript `object.property`. `@Model.BasePrice` will get replaced by the Razor templating engine _on the server_ with the actual value before it ever gets to the browser, whereby the browser will see an invalid javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your `@Model` properties in that function like you would in Razor.  There are several ways you can do this, but assuming you stick with the `onchange()` approach, you will need to add some way to access your BasePrice property in JavaScript.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BasePrice, new {id = "basePrice"})
```

Then, your script would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function OnPriceChange(val) {
            $("#basePrice").val($("#basePrice").val() + val);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Razor code is parsed in the server before its sent to the view, so `function OnPriceChange(val) { @Model.BasePrice = @Model.BasePrice + val; };` evaluates to `100 = 100 + val;` when the page is first rendered (assuming `BasePrice = 100`). In order to make this work, change the html to

```
<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BasePrice)</dt>
<dd id="baseprice">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BasePrice)</dd>

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="price" value="@item.Price" />
    @item.Name
  </label>
}
```

and modify the script to

```
var price = new Number('@Model.BasePrice'); // assign initial value
var element = ('#baseprice'); // cache it
$('.price').change(function() { // handle the change event of the checkboxes
  var item = new Number($(this).val()); // get the item value
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    price += item;
  } else {
    price -= item;
  }
  element.text(price);
});
```

Note this assumes if you check a checkbox, you want to increase the base price by the amount of the item, and if you uncheck it, reduce the price by the amount of the item.

It also does not format the value. For example if you wanted to output `$100.00`, then you would need something like

```
element.text('$' + price.toFixed(2));
```